# crashed "Ctrl-g" at "emacs -nw "

Tags: terminal, emacs

% uname -a

Linux xxxxxxx 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

% emacs --version

GNU Emacs 26.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

% gnome-terminal --version

# GNOME Terminal 3.36.1.1 using VTE 0.60.3 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD

% emacs -nw test.c

when editing..

stroke "Ctrl-g"

crashed and display prompt

%

why??

Comment: That's strange. Is it possible that you accidentally activated the [Emergency Escape](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emergency-Escape.html#Emergency-Escape)?

Answer (score 0):

Try `emacs -nw -Q test.c`.

That is, try Emacs without your init file: `emacs -Q`.

Then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: thank u.         try to "emacs -nw -Q test.c", but storked "Ctrl-g", and crashed..